# How to add jquery tool tip on bing map push pin

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

how to add jquery tool tip on bing map push pin  i am facing issue on bing map push pin mouse hower info window having flickring .. Please suggest. using javascript /jquery

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be not to have jQuery/JavaScript tooltip, because your tooltip won't move if user move the maps using mouse/touch/zoom events.

Try with Bing InfoBox which has lots of features and default functionality baked in.

Comment: Thanks for replying ... Actually currently i  am using infobox.. but i wnat to use info box as bing map using in Main site..how to use theme info box ...Please suggest.